# Decrease self priority for a short period and then increase it back

Tags: ruby, linux, process, linux-kernel

In some cases, I want to decrease the running process priority **to execute a costy operation** and then increase it back to the original value. The process should do it **by itself, without root permission**.

I've tried to that inside a ruby app with `Process.setpriority`.

Ins't it a flaw in kernel's design?

Here it is an example in shell:

```
$ nice
0
```

Then

```
$ renice -n 19 -p $$ 
5094 (process' ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
```

Then

```
$ renice -n 0 -p $$
renice: failed to set priority for 5094 (process' ID): Permission denied
```

Comment: if users were allowed to renice to a higher priority, they would always increase it to a maximum, selfish as they are. that would be a flaw.

Comment: brauliobo, what is your linux kernel version (or just show output of `uname -a`)

Comment: @Pavel the kernel could save the original priority and allow the process to set it back to it or a lower value

Comment: @osgx `Linux brauliolaptop 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: This is strange, because since 2.6.12 version of kernel, linux allows process to renice to higher priority, if RLIMIT_NICE is set correctly (check it): http://man7.org/conf/lca2006/Linux_2.6_changes/rlimit_5.html http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority Or universal ways: 1) get the CAP_SYS_NICE privilege (usually from root); or 2) fork second  process to do the low-priority work and renice only it. Or 3) call [sched_yield](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) often when doing low-priority work.

Comment: @osgx how to set RLIMIT_NICE system-wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually only root (or processes with CAP_SYS_NICE privilege) may change their "nice" to higher priority (lower values). But since 2.6.12 version of kernel (http://man7.org/conf/lca2006/Linux_2.6_changes/rlimit_5.html), linux introduced additional way to increasing priority (lowering nice), the RLIMIT_NICE rlimit (man getrlimit). You can check it with `ulimit -e` in bash, and change by root before switching  (su) to usual user or to nobody ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44334/is-there-any-use-for-rlimit-nice)).

So, what can you do to make your process temporary having low priority (higher nice value):

1. Get the CAP_SYS_NICE privilege from root
2. Set right RLIMIT_NICE (default is 0, so RLIMIT_NICE is disabled and this is the flaw in linux distributions), either by root `ulimit -e VALUE` or in system-wide `/etc/security/limits.conf`, item `nice` (this config is used by `pam_limits.so` PAM module, so check, is it called before you start the process. Usually it is called by login, *dm managers, crond and atd. Don't know is it called for processes started by init.d scripts)

Two examples of second variant from [brauliobo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670229/brauliobo), allow nice back to 0, system-wide. Add to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*              soft    nice    0 # ranges from -20 to 19
```

Or using `sudo` to root to change RLIMIT_NICE for single shell:

```
sudo bash
ulimit -e 20 # equivalent to 0, as it ranges from 0 to 40
sudo -u youruser bash
# now you can renice back to 0
```

---

Without help from root user you can:

1. Fork second process to do the low-priority work and renice only it. Use inter-process communication to send work items and get results.
2. You can call `sched_yield` often when doing low-priority work. This will enable other processes to preempt your program early.

Comment: for my logged user, `ulimit -e` already returns 0, but I can't set priority back to 0

Comment: also, `limits.conf` use a different format, I don't how to do `ulimit -e V` from there

Comment: `ulimit -e` values are shifted by 20 (are in range 0..40; set 20 to enable renicing back to "0"), and `nice` values are not shifted when used by renice (they are in range -20..19): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/getrlimit.2.html "*The actual ceiling for the  nice  value is  calculated   as   20 - rlim_cur. (This strangeness  occurs because negative numbers cannot be specified as resource limit values,  since  they  typically  have  special meanings...)*". And according to man `limits.conf(5)`, limits.conf will accept `[-20,19]` range, but I would like to double check this.